# make data frame with binaries to sum to 1

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame with only zeros and ones, e.g.

```
df <- data.frame(v1 = rbinom(100, 1, 0.5), 
                 v2 = rbinom(100, 1, 0.2),
                 v3 = rbinom(100, 1, 0.4))
```

Now I want to modify this data set so that each row sums to 1.

So this

```
1 0 0
1 1 0
0 0 1
1 1 1
0 0 0
```

should become this:

```
1    0    0
0.5  0.5  0
0    0    1
0.33 0.33 0.33
0    0    0
```

edit: rows with all zeros should be left as is

Comment: what if you have a row with v1=v2=v3=0 ?

Comment: @RHertel good point, that should be kept as is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a quick method:

```
# create matrix
temp <- matrix(c(1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1), ncol=3, byrow=T)

temp / rowSums(temp)
```

This exploits the fact that matrices are ordered column-wise, so that the element by element division of `rowsSums` and the recycling are aligned.

In the case that all elements in a row are zero, and you don't want an `Inf`, another method from @RHertel s is the following:

```
# save rowSum:
mySums <- rowSums(temp)
temp / ifelse(mySums != 0,  mySums, 1)
```

Comment: thanks, but I forgot to mention that rows with only zeros should be left zero. Your solution produces NaN for those

Answer (score 5):

As already pointed out by @lmo the data.frame (or matrix) can be modified with

```
df <- df / rowSums(df)
```

In the case of rows containing only zeros this will lead to rows containing only `NaN`. Since these rows should be kept as they were, the easiest way is probably to correct for this afterwards with

```
df[is.na(df)] <- 0
```